# Prove function with removable singularities is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I usually have trouble writing in detail why a specific function with removable singularities is holomorphic. Let $f$ be a holomorphic fuunction in the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$, where $f(\mathbb{D})\subset \mathbb{D}$ and $f$ has zeros at $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in \mathbb{D}$. Let
$$B(z)=\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{z-a_j}{1-z\overline{a_j}}$$
and finally let $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{B(z)}$. I want to prove that $g(z)$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$. I know that the singularities $a_1,\ldots, a_n$ are removable (proved it using Riemann's theorem) and I know about a corollary that says that if $g$ is holomorphic in a domain except for some removable singularities and is continuous in the whole domain, then it is holomorphic in the whole domain. However I am having trouble proving that it is continuous. Can someone help me? Is there another (maybe easier) way to prove that $g$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$?

Comment: it is enough for $g$ to be bounded at a removable singularity, as that implies $g$ holomorphic, and here it is very easy to see that $f/B$ is bounded on small discs around the zeroes, so it is holomorphic there

Comment: @Conrad why is that? Isn't that an equivalent condition to being a removable singularity? I believe that is what Riemann's theorem says

Comment: near a zero $a$ of order $k \ge 1$, one has $f(z)=(z-a)^kh(z)$ with $h$ analytic and non zero at $a$; same for $B(z)=B_1(z)(z-a)^k$ by construction, so the ratio is $h/B_1$ which is even directly seen to be holomorphic without any theorem since $h(a) \ne 0, B_1(a) \ne 0$; regarding Riemann's theorem, note that at an isolated singularity, a holomorphic function can either be extended there, or it goes to infinity, or it spreads throughout the plane, so in particular it is quite unbounded on some parts, so in particular boundness (and even milder conditions) exclude the last two cases

Comment: @Conrad Okay but according to Riemann's theorem, that means that $g$ can me holomorphically extended, but that doesn't mean that $g$ is actually holomorphic

Comment: @kubo This is a slight abuse of terminology we always encounter in complex analysis, mainly because if a holomorphic function on an open set has a holomorphic extension, then that extension is unique, which is why we use the same letter to denote the original function and the extended one as well. So, although we should strictly speaking say "$g$ has a holomorphic extension to $D$", we simply say "$g$ is holomorphic on $D$".